# MS Excel VBA - Selecting multiple distinct dynamic ranges

Tags: excel, vba, range

I need to copy the data in various columns that are not next to each other and that will have a variable number of rows (but that variable will have the same value for each column).

My code so far is as follows:

```
 Set MyXL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
 MyXL.Workbooks.Add
 MyXL.Worksheets(1).Name = SheetName 

 Set shtData = Worksheets("Data")
 rngDataRowCount = shtData.Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row
 Set rngData = shtData.Range("A1:I" & rngDataRowCount)
 rngData.Copy

 MyXL.Worksheets(SheetName).Activate
 MyXL.Worksheets(SheetName).Paste
 Range("A1").Select
```

Which works fine as long as the columns are next to each other but doesn't allow me to add others.

I was hoping I could do something like:

```
     Set rngData = shtData.Range("A1:I, N1:N, P1:R" & rngDataRowCount)
```

But this statement fails. Alternatively is there any way I can Set multiple ranges and then append to the clipboard? Any help is, of course, appreciated.

**EDIT:** To clarify what I'm trying to achieve let's say I have the following table:

```
 _________________________________________________________
 | col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5 | col6 | col7 | col8 |
 _________________________________________________________
 | q    | w    | e    | r    | t    | y    | u    | i    |
 _________________________________________________________
 | q    | w    | e    | r    | t    | y    | u    | i    |
 _________________________________________________________
```

I want to be able to select a range say col1, col2, col5 and col8 so that it copies all filled cells in those columns in one go so that pasting gives me this:

```
 _____________________________
 | col1 | col2 | col5 | col8 |
 _____________________________
 | q    | w    | t    | i    |
 _____________________________
 | q    | w    | t    | i    |
 _____________________________
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this could be an idea for you, just to use the loop.

**Edited to make it clear:** As a result you will copy each column separately. Column-to-copy order will be kept. If you keep constant destination range rules each column will be copied into appropriate range with the same order.

```
Sub Answer()
    Dim shtData As Worksheet
    Set shtData = Worksheets("Data")
    Dim rngDataRowCount
    rngDataRowCount = shtData.Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row
    Dim rngData As Range

    '<--start of modification
    Dim rngCol As Range
    Set rngData = shtData.Range("A1:I" & rngDataRowCount & _
                    ",N1:N" & rngDataRowCount & _
                    ",P1:R" & rngDataRowCount)

'<---variant A- keep columns separated into destination range
    For Each rngCol In rngData.Columns
         rngCol.Copy rngCol.Offset(0, 20)   'here, 20 columns to right
    Next
**'here edited**

'<---variant B- copy columns into new location, united, no loop
         rngData.Copy Range("zz1")           'here, set destination as single top-left cell
End Sub
```

One tip- if you copy your columns into other Range use syntax as presented `Range.Copy destinationRange`

Comment: That assumes that my columns are always a fixed amount of columns (here 20) apart right? In that case what is the benefit of: 

    ("A1:I" & rngDataRowCount & _ ",N1:N" & rngDataRowCount & _ ",P1:R" & rngDataRowCount)

Over:

    ("A1:R" & rngDataRowCount)

Comment: As I understand you don't have continuous column range, in `Range("A:R")` some are missing, you take some of them only. The benefit is that you can set columns you need in `rngData` variable and copy than each column separately from that range only. There could be some alternative techniques which depend of the way you prefer to set `rngData`.

Comment: Oh I see - If I set the range that way is there any way I can copy all the columns in one go rather than separately? Thanks for the help by the way

Comment: see the code after edition. There are two options now for you- to copy as separated or united columns. hope it helps you... Use either variant A or variant B, not both at the same time.

Comment: Thanks for that! I'm using variant B but I'm now getting a runtime error because my paste method is failing I have included my paste method in the OP now - how can I make it work with this code?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28297/discussion-between-db579-and-kazjaw)